# I'm stuck scraping this website - got to 85%

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape this website for the past week. I want to think that I got pretty far yet there's this last error that I can't seem to solve. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Website: https://everynoise.com/new_releases_by_genre.cgi?genre=local&region=NL&date=20230428&hidedupes=on

The problem with the below code is that it theoretically gets everything I want. However, when scraping the releases under a specific genre the df isn't formatted in a way where you have the artist and releases categorized under the genre, per row.

I now get all the releases and artists for a specific genre as a list in a single row/cell... but the genre is returned in my df as multiple rows as it should.

I tried multiple things;

- different loop structure
- different div class elements
- different append to df methods

I'm lost... this is the code I've used;

```
genre_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='genrename')

for genre_div in genre_divs:
    # Extract the genre name from the h2 element
    genre_name = genre_div.text

    # Extract the genre link from the div element
    genre_link = genre_div.find('a').get('href')
    
    # Find all albumbox div elements under this genre div
    album_divs = genre_div.find_next_siblings('div', class_='albumbox album')
    
    for album_div in album_divs:
        # Extract the artist name from the b element
        artist_names = [b.text for b in album_div.find_all('b')]
        # Extract the title attributes from the a elements
        title_attrs = [a.get('title') for a in album_div.find_all('a')]
        # Extract the artist links from the a elements that contain 'Aartist' in the href attribute
        artist_links = [a.get('href') for a in album_div.find_all('a') if 'Aartist' in a.get('href')]
        # Extract the album urls from the a elements that contain 'onclick' in the attribute
        album_urls = [a.get('href') for a in album_div.find_all('a') if 'onclick' in a.attrs]

        # append a dictionary for each album to the data list
        for artist_name, title, artist_link, album_url in zip(artist_names, title_attrs, artist_links, album_urls):
            data["Genre"].append(genre_name)
            data["Artist"].append(artist_name)
            data["Title"].append(title)
            data["Artist_Link"].append(artist_link)
            data["Album_URL"].append(album_url)
            data["Genre_Link"].append(genre_link)
        # create a pandas dataframe from the data list
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

output df.
The list of artists in the first row should fall under just one genre `\nelectro house 30`. The second row/list of artists should fall under the second listed genre on the website. I want to releases/artists shown per row. Not in a list within a cel and incorrectly mapped re. genre.

````
0        \nelectro house 30    
1        \nelectro house 30    
2        \nelectro house 30    
3        \nelectro house 30    
4        \nelectro house 30    
...                      ...   
2551          \ndutch dnb 2    
2552          \ndutch dnb 2    
2553  \ngospel papiamento 1    
2554  \ngospel papiamento 1    
2555   \ngrunneger muziek 1    

                                                 Artist  \
0     [Dyro, Dannic, Nicky Romero, Quintino, Bassjac...   
1     [Disfunktion, KAAZE, Basto, Tristan Garner, Na...   
2     [Dennis Cartier, Charmes, Jay Lima, BODYWORX, ...   
3     [Rank 1, Ferry Corsten, Armin van Buuren, Armi...   
4     [Dastic, Wyko, MR.BLACK, Ryos, Meikle, Timmy T...   
...                                                 ...   
2551                             [Eliazar-El Mensajero]   
2552                                          [Kriegel]   
2553                             [Eliazar-El Mensajero]   
2554                                          [Kriegel]   
2555                                          [Kriegel]   

                                            title_attrs  \
0     [artist 2 in genre\nNL rank 13,638, None, arti...   
1     [artist 105 in genre\nNL rank 98,054, None, ar...   
2     [artist 107 in genre\nNL rank 175,230, None, a...   
3     [artist 15 in genre\nNL rank 16,021, None, art...   
4     [artist 15 in genre\nNL rank 19,476, None, art...   
...                                                 ...   
2551      [artist 29 in genre\nNL rank 2,039,570, None]   
2552      [artist 43 in genre\nNL rank 2,146,816, None]   
2553      [artist 29 in genre\nNL rank 2,039,570, None]   
2554      [artist 43 in genre\nNL rank 2,146,816, None]   
2555      [artist 43 in genre\nNL rank 2,146,816, None]   

                                           artist_links  \
0     [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A03MVmfitJTVJIxYm...   
1     [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A1sXOD5MDspxw6Me8...   
2     [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A0Iyc9gAnfeZEwZnt...   
3     [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A1eQe86RbDKRIiGZk...   
4     [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A1wdU1J2NHzcDYarT...   
...                                                 ...   
2551  [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A4t793XpAv8YS1EwS...   
2552  [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A0sI0xeN6TwvJ1djK...   
2553  [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A4t793XpAv8YS1EwS...   
2554  [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A0sI0xeN6TwvJ1djK...   
2555  [?genre=%21spotify%3Aartist%3A0sI0xeN6TwvJ1djK...   

                                             album_urls  \
0     [spotify:album:4u42n51sa2xF2urqL1VgzK, spotify...   
1     [spotify:album:3Pc6lNhhKMEgYzYjJr4xh8, spotify...   
2     [spotify:album:0TIEn7BCmwZlv3iHRuKlMr, spotify...   
3     [spotify:album:7nv70z42Hk4gMJoLQAEeHK, spotify...   
4     [spotify:album:7d7AOxGnjwIaJ1niuNBIk3, spotify...   
...                                                 ...   
2551             [spotify:album:41BRZt3SZrK7ttRhkiSAHF]   
2552             [spotify:album:3o9MVU9Y1TOMrQvK1zjqpo]   
2553             [spotify:album:41BRZt3SZrK7ttRhkiSAHF]   
2554             [spotify:album:3o9MVU9Y1TOMrQvK1zjqpo]   
2555             [spotify:album:3o9MVU9Y1TOMrQvK1zjqpo]   

                                             Genre_Link  
0     ?genre=electro%20house&region=NL&date=20230428...  
1     ?genre=electro%20house&region=NL&date=20230428...  
2     ?genre=electro%20house&region=NL&date=20230428...  
3     ?genre=electro%20house&region=NL&date=20230428...  
4     ?genre=electro%20house&region=NL&date=20230428...```
````

Comment: what is the final output you are expecting can you add a  sample

Comment: added to my initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100%  sure about the output you are expecting but i have made minor corrections and it will generate data like this, haven't made any change in the part where you extract the Album Data wasn't sure about that
[image]
Full code

```
url = "https://everynoise.com/new_releases_by_genre.cgi?genre=local&region=NL&date=20230428&hidedupes=on"
data = {
    "Genre": [],
    "Artist": [],
    "Title": [],
    "Artist_Link": [],
    "Album_URL": [],
    "Genre_Link": []
}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
genre_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='genrename')

for genre_div in genre_divs:
    # Extract the genre name from the h2 element
    genre_name = genre_div.text

    # Extract the genre link from the div element
    genre_link = genre_div.find('a').get('href')

    # Find all albumbox div elements under this genre div
    album_divs = genre_div.find_next_sibling('div').findChildren("div", class_='albumbox album')

    for album_div in album_divs:
        # Extract the artist name from the b element
        artist_names = [b.text for b in album_div.find_all('b')]
        # Extract the title attributes from the a elements
        title_attrs = [a.get('title') for a in album_div.find_all('a')]
        # Extract the artist links from the a elements that contain 'Aartist' in the href attribute
        artist_links = [a.get('href') for a in album_div.find_all('a') if 'Aartist' in a.get('href')]
        # Extract the album urls from the a elements that contain 'onclick' in the attribute
        album_urls = [a.get('href') for a in album_div.find_all('a') if 'onclick' in a.attrs]

        # append a dictionary for each album to the data list
        for artist_name, title, artist_link, album_url in zip(artist_names, title_attrs, artist_links, album_urls):
            data["Genre"].append(genre_name)
            data["Artist"].append(artist_name)
            data["Title"].append(title)
            data["Artist_Link"].append(artist_link)
            data["Album_URL"].append(album_url)
            data["Genre_Link"].append(genre_link)
        # create a pandas dataframe from the
    # create a pandas dataframe from the data list
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel("data.xlsx")
```

Comment: you are a hero! this works :))